# docker: understanding image layers after building an image and after starting a container

Tags: docker

I have build a docker image using the Dockerfile:

--Dockerfile

```
FROM scratch
ADD archlinux.tar /
ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8
CMD ["/usr/bin/bash"]
```

--building the docker image:

```
docker build -t archlinux/base .
```

then checking the images:

```
$ docker images  
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
archlinux/base      latest              7f4e7832243a        43 minutes ago      399MB
```

then go into the overlay2 folder and check what happens

```
 root@  cd var/lib/docker/overlay2 
#  ls -al
0d5db16fa33657d952e4d7921d9239b5a17ef579e03ecdd5046b63fc47d15038
```

now i try to run:

```
$ docker run -it archlinux/base
```

Now check the /var/lib/overlay2 folder

```
#  ls -al
total 24
drwx------  6 root  root  4096 Mar  3 15:58 .
drwx--x--x 15 simha users 4096 Mar  3 07:25 ..
drwx------  3 root  root  4096 Mar  3 16:01 0d5db16fa33657d952e4d7921d9239b5a17ef579e03ecdd5046b63fc47d15038
drwx------  4 root  root  4096 Mar  3 16:01 500ef7ee5672b73c778e2080dda0ad7a9101d6b65e5bdb0b52f4e5d2f22fa2b3
drwx------  4 root  root  4096 Mar  3 15:58 500ef7ee5672b73c778e2080dda0ad7a9101d6b65e5bdb0b52f4e5d2f22fa2b3-init
drwx------  2 root  root  4096 Mar  3 15:58 l
```

Now i see more folders.

Why there was only one folder before the run and later it shows many folders in the overlay2.

If the check the images using docker command it shows the same as previous:

```
$ docker images  
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
archlinux/base      latest              7f4e7832243a        43 minutes ago      399MB
```

How to understand the image and their layers in overlay2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that the contents of the `/var/lib/docker/` directory is for the internal soup of Docker and should not be messed with.

In that directory, the contents of the `overlay2` directory is to store the docker layers that constitute your docker images and containers. What is important to remember is that [overlay2](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/#how-the-overlay2-driver-works) is a file system using [union mounts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_mount). In short, it will *merge* two folders into one. So when using the filesystem you might see one folder, but under the hood there are more. This is how docker makes [*layers*](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/#images-and-layers).

Comment: Just wanted to know that /overlay2 stores the filesystem related layers only. And the /image/overlay2 folder constitute information about all images and their image layers.